# Pandas new Column with list comprehension and an if statement with reference to existings columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to add a new column to a DataFrame with list comprehension and an if statement, this way:

```
SD['Ln(aT) ANALYTIC'] = [x + 1 for x in SD['T'] if SD['T'] >= SD['TG']]
```

and I get this error:

```
 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
 a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I don´t know how to handle this problem.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** DataFrame looks like:

[image]

Comment: That's because `SD['T']` is not just some scalar value. It's length is more than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Bazingaa... How do i get the Scalar of each value with the position of x for the if statement?

Comment: It wold be helpful if you will share some small dataset from your dataframe to show how it looks like. jezrael, who answered, is waiting for that ;)

Comment: ok, i will edit my question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with boolean mask:

```
mask = SD['T'] >= SD['TG']
SD['Ln(aT) ANALYTIC'] = np.where(mask, SD['T'] + 1, SD['T'])
```

Or:

```
SD['Ln(aT) ANALYTIC'] = np.where(mask, SD['T'] + 1, np.nan)
```

List comprehesnion is possible, but slow:

```
SD['Ln(aT) ANALYTIC1'] = [i + 1 if i >= j else i for i, j in zip(SD['T'], SD['TG'])]
```

---

```
SD = pd.DataFrame({'T': [1,2,3],
                   'TG':[2,5,1]})

#[3000 rows x 2 columns]
SD = pd.concat([SD] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [294]: %timeit SD['Ln(aT) ANALYTIC1'] = [i + 1 if i >= j else i for i, j in zip(SD['T'], SD['TG'])]
1.18 ms ± 82.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [295]: %timeit SD['Ln(aT) ANALYTIC2'] = np.where(SD['T'] >= SD['TG'], SD['T'] + 1, SD['T'])
511 µs ± 16.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Can you also add some little explanation to your code? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Bazingaa - sure, but thinking what OP want ;)

Comment: Here you go. Shoot!

Comment: is the third part of the np.where() statement the "else"? :)

Comment: @NilsKohlmey: I think the way you were originally doing it using list comprehension, you would need `enumerate` to access the same index element from `TG`. But you already got a better solution now

Comment: @NilsKohlmey - added solution for list comprehension with timings.